# GAMS: Using variables in logical conditions

Tags: dollar-sign, gams-math

I got a question about GAMS. I'm kind of a beginner with GAMS.
I'm using minlp with scip solver.

I'm trying to model a system for a thermal energy storage of a concentrated solar power plant.
I'm right now stuck on modeling the equations for the tank operation strategy, so whether it's on discharging or charging mode. I'm modelling a thermocline tank, where while charging the hot htf enters from the top of the tank and pushes out cold htf from the bottom. For the discharging process it's the other way around.

The operational strategies dependent on the mass flows from the receiver or the power block, which are decision variables. For the different operational strategies the inlet and outlet temperature of the thermal energy storage changes. So there are some equations which logically depent on the values of decision variables.

The thing is, that if I try to use logical conditions (either with the if operator or the $ operator) with variables in it for the definition of equations, I get the errors 52 or 53 "Endogenous $-control operations not allowed". This seems to be an error you get with the solve statements, because it is not possible to put in logical conditions with decision variables. After doing some research on the internet I found these threats, where it is explained quite nicely:

https://forum.gamsworld.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=6795

[Use variable in GAMS dollar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861471/use-variable-in-gams-dollar)

So ouf of this problem I got some questions:

Does anyone know a possible way, where I can model equations, which logically depend on decision variables? Or is this not possible with GAMS, so that I would need to switch to another language to solve this problem?

These would be the important equations:

```
e_charge(i+1)$(m_rc_ts(i+1) > 0) .. dec(i+1) =e= 1;

e_discharge(i+1)$(m_pb_ts(i+1)) .. dec(i+1) =e= 2;

e_no_use(i+1)$(m_rc_ts(i+1) = 0 and m_pb_ts(i+1) = 0) .. dec(i+1) =e= dec(i);

e_m_rc_ts_restrict(i+1)$(dec(i+1) = 2) .. m_rc_ts(i+1) =e= 0;

e_m_pb_ts_restrict(i+1)$(dec(i+1) = 1) .. m_pb_ts(i+1) =e= 0;

e_T_ti_charge(nfirst,i+1)$(dec(i+1)= 1) .. T_fl(nfirst,i+1) =e= T_ro;

e_T_ti_discharge(nfirst,i+1)$(dec(i+1)= 2) .. T_fl(nfirst,i+1) =e= T_po(i+1);
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the variable per se, but you are able to use its attributes:
so you cannot write

```
$(dec(i+1))
```

but

```
$(dec.l(i+1))
```

works (it is the level of the variable).